# Shift/reduce conflit in Bison

Tags: c, bison

I have many errors in my bison parser and even if it works well, I'd like to understand these conflict.
Code looks like that:

lexer:

```
id          ([[:alpha:]]|_)([[:alnum:]]|_)*
%%

{id} {
  yylval.val=strdup(yytext);
  return(ID);
}
```

parser:

```
%union {
char* val;
}

%token<val> ID
%type<val> DD1 DD

%start Input

%%

Input:
      %empty
    | DD
;
DD:
    DD1 ID {$$=strcat($1, $2);}
DD1:
      %empty {$$=strdup("");}
    | ID    {$$=$1;}
;
%%
```

Errors are: `1 shift/reduce conflict` and `rule useless because of conflicts: %empty...`
Could someone help me ? Thanks.

ps: it's not my actual code, I know the strcat won't work etc, this is just an outline of the issue.

Answer (score 1):

When the parser sees an ID in state with items

```
DD <- . DD1 ID
```

and

```
DD1 <- . ID,
```

...it does not know if it should epsilon-reduce the `DD` and proceed to item with state

```
 DD <- DD1 . ID
```

or shift the `ID` and proceed to the state with item

```
 DD1 <- ID .
```

This is your S/R conflict. The parser generated will always prefer to shift to resolve the S/R, so the reduce never happens and consequently the `DD1: %empty` rule is useless.

You can simply switch the order of the third rule to fix this and still have a `DD` be "one or two ID".

```
DD:
    ID DD1 {$$=strcat($1, $2);}
```

Comment: (up to getting the memory management aspects of strcat correct, etc)

Comment: Ok I understand better now. However, I think your solution doesn't really fix the issue. I mean, indeed I can do that to have "one or two ID", but it is not consistent to what DD1 and ID means.
My idea was to say "in the language, DD is an ID with possibly a property DD1".
It's like, in C you could write `int a;` or just `a;` for the same result.
I think the only possibility is to use a delimiter.

Comment: Well, your question was "why", and I answered it - the "fix" was just a bonus.  :)   Two other tips - 1) Try to avoid using epsilons / `%empty`.  You can always re-write your grammar to not use them and recognize the same language, and in a lot of cases (your example is one of them), it's not too many extra lines.  2) Don't expect your grammar's AST to perfectly mirror the semantic structure of your language.  It won't.  Your actions can start to build the semantic value  tree, or you could just generate a structure faithful to the AST and do a pass over it to transform it as you like.

Comment: (nonteminal DD parses as .... == syntactic structure.   There is a DD construct in the language which might have property...  == (denotational) semantic structure)

Comment: Thanks for your remark :) I understand that my AST might not reflect the semantic but it's quite easier haha. I will try to remove the %empty in my code. I didn't understand the second comment however.